# Insert list data over the iteration(map)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here I am trying to modify my data over the iteration and send some result to API call.

The API Call receives a request with a structured data format which is

```
{ list: [{ id: "1", name: "Hello"  }, ... ] }
```

Somehow I managed to call the API with single data ( const params in my current code, it only accepts single data).

But now it has to be done with multiple data something like this:

```
{ list: [{ id: "1", name: "Hello"  }, { id: "22", name: "Ed"  }, { id: "36", name: "Jason"  } ... ] }
```

Here is my current code

```
const [table, setTalbe] = useState(..);   // assume, we have some table data here

const processNow = () => {
  
    let id = 0;
    let name = '';

    // if table length is greater than 1, we go for the loop.
    if (table.length >= 1) {
      table.map(data => {
        id = data.userId;
        name = data.userName;
      });

      //insert table data to params, here I want to add whole table data into "list"
      //the final result of this list should be something like this
      //ex ) list: [{ id: '123', name: 'Josh' }, { id: '125', name: 'Sue' }, { id: '2222', name: 'Paker' } ...],
      // but how??

      const params: any = {
        list: [
          {
            id: id,
            name: name
          },
        ],
      };
    
      //send PUT reqeust with params
      axios
        .put(
          '/api/v1/tosent',
          params,
        )
        .then(res => {
          console.log('The response', res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('The error: ', err);
        });
    }
  };
```

but I'm stuck with it, please help me to finish this code to work properly.
need your kind advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` returns a new array with the function you pass applied to every element. You should study the [MDN documentation on map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to understand its use.

Your current code does nothing with the map return value:

```
      table.map(data => {
        id = data.userId;
        name = data.userName;
      });
```

You probably assumed `.map` would *mutate* the data, as in change it in place. Instead, the whole operation returns a new array.

It looks like you want to do:

```
      const list = table.map(data => {
        return {
          id: data.userId,
          name: data.userName
        }
      });
```

This is applying a function to every element in the array that will map each element to a new *object*, matching your question, with an `id` and `name` key. Then it looks like you want to pass the returned value of `map` (which we named `list` above) to your call:

```
      const params: any = {
        list: list
      };
```

Comment: Thank you for the super details. it solved my codes.